# Text doesn't appear tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

count = 0
while count >= 0 :
    print(count)
    time.sleep(1)
    count = count + 1


root= Tk()


label1= Label(root, text='Gegevens', bg='lightblue')
label2= Label(root, text='Voortgang')
labelfiets_prestatie= Label (root, text='Fiets_Prestatie',)
labelStappen= Label(root, text='Meter', command= count, bg='red')


label1.pack(fill= X)
label2.pack()
labelfiets_prestatie.pack()
labelStappen.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Now my problem is that whenever I delete the count code the GUI appears, but I want the numbers that are generated to be seen in the GUI. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Don't use `.sleep()` with `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `after` method.

> This method registers a callback function that will be called after a
>   given number of milliseconds. Tkinter guarantees that the callback
>   will not be called earlier than that.

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.poll() # start polling

    def poll(self):
        # do something 
        self.master.after(100, self.poll)
```

You can check out [Tkinter after method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).And if you want to update label ,you can use `update_idletasks`:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
root = Tk()
var = StringVar()   
l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()

count=10
while count>=0:
    sleep(1)
    var.set(count)
    count=count-1
    root.update_idletasks()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is also an example of how to use it to make a simple timer in the docmentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tkinter/6724/delaying-a-function#t=201701301400175181844.